# Save/Load control values (Multiline Textboxes, NumericUpDowns, Checkbox) to/from file

Tags: vb.net, load, save

I am looking for a way to save and load the values of all my controls present in my form.
My form has around 100 controls spread over 7 tabs. The controls include (Multiline) `TextBoxes` (Strings), `NumericUpDowns` (Integers, Decimals) and `Checkboxes` (Booleans).

If the user clicks the save button a "Save File" dialog should appear allowing the user to specify the directory and the filename of the save file.
All the values of the controls should then be written to that file.

If the user clicks the load button an "Open File" should appear where the user can pick a previously saved save file. All the controls should then adopt the values found in the save file.

I have implemented Application Settings in my form, and now when I click save, it saves the control values through `My.Settings.Save()`. If I click load it loads them.
However, my project requires that multiple save files can be made to reflect multiple configurations. As I understand Application Settings only allow for a single .config file in the Application Data folder.

So how can I code a save/load routine to save/load different configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code found at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20917/Creating-a-Custom-Settings-Provider?msg=4266719#xx4266719xx) site provides another Provider to handle the Application Settings. It is possible to code the target destination of the `.settings` files.

I added a `CopyFile` routine to copy the generated `.setting` file to the same directory but with a different name, specified by the user. The code:

> ```
>     If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
>         Dim savefile As String
>         savefile = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
>         Try
>             My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(My.Application.Info.Title & ".settings", savefile, True)
>         Catch ex As Exception
>             MsgBox(ex.Message)
>         End Try
>     Else
>         'Nothing
>     End If
> ```

Now to load the user-saved settings again I've made Load routine which copies the chosen file to the root folder and overwrites "Form1.settings"

> ```
>     If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
>         Dim loadfile As String
>
>         loadfile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
>
>         Try
>             My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(loadfile, My.Application.Info.Title &    ".settings", True)
>         Catch ex As Exception
>             MsgBox(ex.Message)
>         End Try
>         Application.Restart()
>     Else
>         'Nothing
>     End If
> ```

The routine performs an `Application.Restart()` such that the Form1_load event is performed and the controls copy the values in the `.settings` file

> ```
> Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>      TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.Text1 
> End Sub
> ```

Now when the user clicks save, the `My.Settings.Save()` is executed and the `Form1.settings` file is copied to a user specified `.settings` file.
When the user clicks load the user specified `.settings` file is overwriting `Form1.settings` and the application restarts, reading in the values from the `Form1.settings` file.